# How do I assign a output from a get method to 'accountId'

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, html, java, js

I'm struggling to find a way to set my **accountID** value to the returned value of my get **parentAccountName()** method.

The method works and returns the value successfully, but when trying to assign it to **accountId** (this is then passed into a SOQL query inside of an Apex class) it doesn't work.

Tried looking around for countless hours now and can't get to the bottom of why so I'm wondering if someone is able to help me with this.

```
import ACCOUNT_NAME from "@salesforce/schema/Case.Account.Id";

    @wire(getRecord, {
    recordId: '$recordId',
    fields: [Subject, ACCOUNT_NAME]
})
account;

get parentAccountName() {
    return getFieldValue(this.account.data, ACCOUNT_NAME);
}

doInit() {
    init({
            accountId: '$parentAccountName'
        })
        .then(result => {
            this.listOfRelatedOpenComplaints = [];
            result.forEach((row) => {
                console.log(row);
                let rowData = {};
                rowData.Url = '/' + row.Id;
                rowData.Complaint_Reference__c = row.Complaint_Reference__c;
                rowData.Subject = row.Subject;
                rowData.Status = row.Status;
                rowData.CreatedDate = row.CreatedDate;
                this.listOfRelatedOpenComplaints.push(rowData);
            });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })
}
```

Comment: Why do you have a `doInit` function in an LWC? That is an Aura component construct.

Comment: @PhilW It was taken from a guide to help build a data table

Answer (score 1):

Since your row data depends on the result of a wire, you need to ensure that the "initialization" is performed after that wire returns the required value.

Note, also, that `doInit` is not an LWC construct, but rather is Aura's equivalent to the LWC `connectedCallback`. However, you cannot use LWC's `connectedCallback` because this would be called before the wire has been invoked.

In addition, only wires use "dynamic, reactive" parameters referenced via the $name syntax. Imperative calls (such as the one you do to `init`) should just receive the required value. In this case I'm guessing you actually need the ID rather than name of the Account...

So, try changing the LWC to something like:

```
// Holds the wire data
account;

@wire(getRecord, {
    recordId: '$recordId',
    fields: [Subject, ACCOUNT_NAME]
})
receiveAccount({data, error}) {
    if (data) {
        this.account = data;
        doInit();
    }

    if (error) {
        ...; // React to an error in some appropriate way
    }
}

get parentAccountName() {
    if (this.account) {
        return getFieldValue(this.account, ACCOUNT_NAME);
    }

    return null;
}

doInit() {
    init({
            // Pass the required value. I'm guessing it should be the
            // account ID, which is actually already in recordId
            accountId: this.recordId
        })
        .then(result => {
            this.listOfRelatedOpenComplaints = [];
            result.forEach((row) => {
                console.log(row);
                let rowData = {};
                rowData.Url = '/' + row.Id;
                rowData.Complaint_Reference__c = row.Complaint_Reference__c;
                rowData.Subject = row.Subject;
                rowData.Status = row.Status;
                rowData.CreatedDate = row.CreatedDate;
                this.listOfRelatedOpenComplaints.push(rowData);
            });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })
}
```

Comment: Hi Phil,

Thanks so much for the reply already! I appreciate the help... I should have specified, the LWC is intended for the Case page, and the purpose of the LWC is to retrieve (and display in the datatable) a list of Complaint Cases (custom record type) related to the Account.

So based off that, I'm guessing accountId: this.recordID' wouldn't retrieve the records I need as it's going off the current Case record Id, and not the Case's parent, account ID?

Comment: If you have the correct account ID in `this.account` then you can use `this.account.Id` to access the account's ID.

Comment: Oh, and obviously the fetching of the account itself would need adjusting accordingly. I guess the `this.account` would actually be `this.case` and `this.case.accountId` would be the field you want to use to pass the account ID...?